# main thread is NULL in swift even though I specified running on main thread

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

I am fetching Contact on myphone Using that code

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let allowedCharset = CharacterSet
            .decimalDigits
        let store = CNContactStore()
        //store.requestAccess(for: .contacts, complete:() -> ()) { (granted,err) in
        store.requestAccess(for: .contacts) { (granted, err) in
            if let error = err
            {
                print("failed to access",error)
                return
            }
            if (granted)
            {
                print(Thread.current)}
```

However I found that UI is freezing and I am getting that the current thread is NULL even though I specified it to run on mainThread.

print(Thread.current) =

Comment: What is freezing here? There are only `print` statements.

Comment: I didnot post the whole I have UITableView where I update my contacts. when I scroll it is freezing. I tried to check and I found the thread is NULL

Comment: Ok, but you should at least show (a) where do you start your `DispatchQueue.main.async` call, and what you do in the `store.requestAccess` completion handler.

Comment: I usually accept the contact access request then I store in UITableView when I am scrolling the UITableview it freezes. By the way that Only happens after I accept the contact access request the first time. IF I open my app again everything works fine. I can't really post the whole code because it is very long. I just want to know why it is NULL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you do some UI updates in the completion handler of `store.requestAccess`.

The handler - according to Apple's documentation - is not called in the main (UI) thread, but in an worker thread:

> The completion handler is called on an arbitrary queue. It is recommended that you use CNContactStore instance methods in this completion handler instead of the UI main thread.

Therefore, if you do some UI stuff in here, you *must* dispatch those calles again into the main thread.

Comment: Thanks I will check it and Report back.